# Mysterious iOS crash with tiny stack trace

Tags: ios, stack-trace

I have one user, and only one user, that regularly gets the following crash:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000192e7a984 objc_object::release() + 8
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000192e79474 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 524
2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186855b38 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
3  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186915124 __CFRunLoopRun + 1460
4  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186855dd0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
5  GraphicsServices               0x000000018c53dc0c GSEventRunModal + 168
6  UIKit                          0x0000000189986fc4 UIApplicationMain + 1156
7  MyApp                          0x00000001001a92d0 main (main.m:17)
8  libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000193453aa0 start + 4
```

This is the entire crash, and I have no clue what causes it.

The user has a pretty standard phone, but it only started happening when they got a replacement iPhone 5 earlier this year. Given that timeline and the fact they are the only one with the crash, might the phone itself be at fault?

Is there anywhere I could look for more information to default this information?

Comment: You should use the *Instruments* tool *Zombies* to find the cause of this issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Unless you can reproduce the issue or log what the user did to crash the app there's no way to find the cause here. The programming error usually happened a lot earlier than when the resulting crash occurs.

Comment: Understood. I was hoping someone would see something in the stack trace that I hadn't.